# How do I make a play button for my full page video?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, fullpage.js

I am using fullpage.js in a project and I have been asked to place a play button for user friendliness. So I found a [nice button](http://www.clker.com/cliparts/K/7/2/z/b/U/media-hi.png) to use and cannot figure out how to get it to appear over my video. I did however find an article here on how to play it on click. Here is my video section:

```
<div class="section" id="section2">
    <div id="container">
    <video controls id="myVideo" preload controls>
        <source src="myvideo.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        <source src="myvideo.webm" type="video/webm">
    </video>
    <div class="layer" style="text-align:center;">          
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the css that I am using:

```
#myVideo
    {
        position: absolute;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        top:0;
        right:0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        z-index: 10;
        background-size: 100% 100%;
        background-color: black; 
        background-image: url('images/play.png'); /* does not show */
        background-position: center center;
        background-size: contain;
        object-fit: cover; 
    }
```

and here is my javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#fullpage').fullpage({

            afterRender: function () {
                //playing the video
                $('video').get(0).pause();
            }
        });

    });
</script>
```

For clarification my HTML5 controls show but the grannies and grandpas need a large play button to help them out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you would need to add the button as an HTML element that sits over the video element. You image is set as the background to the video element.

e.g. a div that has the image in

pseudo HTML

```
<div>
  <video>
  </video>
  <div id="play-button"></div>
</div>
```

css (assuming 100px square image)

```
button {
 position: absolute;
 top: 50%;
 left: 50%;
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
 margin: -50px 0 0 -50px;
 background: url(play.png) no-repeat;
}
```

You will need to then add some javascript to the button to tell the video to play when it is clicked

e.g. jQuery

```
$('#play-button').on('click', function(){
  $('video').get(0).play();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using the pseudo class :after

```
.section:after {
        position:absolute;
        z-index:99;
        content: url('http://www.clker.com/cliparts/K/7/2/z/b/U/media-hi.png');
}
```

This should show the image on top of the video.